# Exportar para o excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Bom dia.
Criei um gridview com dados provenientes de uma tabela
Quando executo a função para gerar a planilha Excel, nada acontece, alguem poderia dar uma ajuda no que pode estar acontecendo?
segue código

```
private void ExportaExcel()
{
    string Arquivo = "RelNovosFuncionarios.xls";
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + Arquivo;

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    gvClientes.RenderControl(htw);

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como não houve respostas, a solução estava no page _load

coloquei a instrução
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnGeraExcel);